# Как изменить отображение страницы без перезагрузки?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Буквально недавно подобный вопрос задавал, но сейчас чуть более точно всё объясню, ибо совет с window resize не особо изменил ход событий.

За отвратный пример кода заранее извиняюсь. Я с jquery / js особо не сталкивался, но в данной ситуации для желаемого результата одними возможностями css видимо справиться проблематично. 
Суть работы этого кода :

```js
var mh = 0;
      $(".header_h").each(function () {
        var h_block = ($(this).height());
        if(h_block > mh) { 
          {mh = h_block;
            $(".header_h").height(mh);
          }
        };
      });
```

заключается в следующем : Если какой-то из элементов с указанным классом изменяет свою высоту на большую - все остальные элементы с этим же классом тоже должны изменять свою высоту. Но проблема заключается в том, что это изменение происходит лишь после перезагрузки страницы, как это можно исправить?

Демонстрация происходящего : [video](https://youtu.be/i2ApxXFBUXY) / [site](https://03oziged.github.io/man/)